# update the textfields without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, magento, php

we are using magento multi vendor site

For multiple Product we are displaying price, selling price , quantity...etc in vendor account.

we gave an option for vendor to update all the textfields of single product by clicking on one "update" button. its working fine but after reloading the page its working. 
**i want to update the textfields without reloading the page**

we are using following code for that :

**Phtml**

```
<input type="hidden" name="product_mass_update[]"  value="<?php echo $products->getEntityId(); ?>"/>
<input class="ama1" type = "text" id = "price_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" name= "price[]" value = "<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>" style = ""/>
    <input class="ama1" type = "text" id = "specialprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" name = "specialprice[]" value = "<?php echo $products->getSpecialPrice(); ?>" onblur="updateFieldSpecialPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>')" style = ""/>
```

**Php**

```
public function massupdatesellerproAction(){
    if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
        if(!$this->_validateFormKey()){
             $this->_redirect('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/');
        }
        $ids= $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_mass_update');
        $price= $this->getRequest()->getParam('price');
        $special= $this->getRequest()->getParam('specialprice');
        foreach ($ids as $key => $value) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($value);
    $product->setPrice($price[$key]);
    $product->setSpecialPrice($special[$key]);
    $product->save();
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess( Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Products has been sucessfully deleted from your account'));
        $this->_redirect('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/');


    }}
```

Comment: I am new to this technology . learning php and js.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/43555/how-do-i-call-a-controller-function-in-ajax

Comment: @Nikhil sure , i will try that....

Comment: @profile-101 no one is going to do your work for you. Just a friendly suggestion; do some research and try something out first before posting a question on StackOverflow. Good luck!

Comment: @Meeseeks Thanks buddy, i have a millions of problems . some i am working on, some i will post here. i will try as much as possible from now before posting here.